# Use a preprocessor directive without using the # character

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, directive

Is there a way to use a preprocessor directive without using the # character in C code?
Can we echo the hash character somehow by using its ASCII etc. equivalents?

> Eg: `1` can be echoed by using `'SOH'` in the .c source file. Is there a similar hack for
>   `'#'`?

Comment: "Echo" how? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: And that you get `1` as output if you print `SOH` is because the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for `SOH` is `1`.

Comment: You cannot "create" preprocessor directives from macros, if that's what you're asking. There's no trick to have a macro produce `#define X`, say, and have that interpreted as preprocessor directive

Comment: I want to type `1` in my c source file, but instead I use `'SOH'`, which equals to `1`. `#` has a hex value too, and it can be used like `char c='\043';` But, I want to use `'\043'include<stdio.h>`. Is there a way ?

Comment: In that case, no there is no such way. And *why* would you want to obfuscate the code like that?

Comment: Also, having `SOH` in the source may make your source unparseable, as it's not in the set of valid characters in the specification.

Comment: You're rather confused. `'SOH'` does not equal 1. Rather, SOH is the name of the ASCII control with a value of `\001`. Likewise, # is the name of the ASCII printable character with a value of `\043`. Anyway, My answer explains alternatives to #, but it would help if you said why you want an alternative.

Comment: I know that `'SOH'` does not equal 1, but translates to 1. I required this help for an obfuscating exercise. Thanks you for your replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the digraph or trigraph equivalent if your compiler supports them (you may need to pass flags to the compiler):

digraph: `%:`

trigraph: `??=`

However, if you're trying to use preprocessor macros to generate preprocessor commands, there's no way to do that.

Comment: Ha, I've found a reason to do this: Make a header file readable by both C and a language where comments start with % (or ?) at the beginning of the line. That's how you could make C preprocessor commands invisible to the non-C language. Handy for reuse of some simple headers between C and Matlab/Octave :)